# Why does running prettier check return error "Couldn't resolve parser "babel-ts"" when using the babel-ts parser?

Tags: typescript, config, prettier

When I call the command check: `prettier --check '**/*.ts' with a prettier config shown below, I receive the error stating that the babel-ts parser is not resolved. I'm currently using prettier 2.3 which does support this [parser](https://prettier.io/blog/2020/03/21/2.0.0.html#babel-as-an-alternative-parser-for-typescript-6400httpsgithubcomprettierprettierpull6400-by-jounqinhttpsgithubcomjounqin--thorn0httpsgithubcomthorn0), so I'm a bit confused as to what I could be doing incorrectly.

```yaml
printWidth: 100
singleQuote: true
trailingComma: all
tabWidth: 2
useTabs: false
overrides:
  - files: "*.ts"
    options:
      parser: babel-ts
```

I've tried using various config formats (js, json, etc) and using the parser config on the root but neither seemed to affect the odd behaviour.

My package config:

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^15.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  }
}
```

test file `index.ts`

```
let a:number = 6
```

Full Error:

```sh
$ prettier --check '*.ts' 
Checking formatting...
index.ts[error] Error: Couldn't resolve parser "babel-ts"
```

Note: Prettier is installed only locally and not globally

Comment: Do you have prettier installed globally and babel-ts NOT installed globally?

Comment: I think you need to share more about your package config and prettier install.

Comment: @cefn Do i need to install babel-ts? Reading through the prettier docs they make no mention to installing additional packages. I thought this may of been the case originally, but i couldnt find any information on it :/

Comment: @justin yes you need to install parsers

Comment: Speculating here from what I can see via the Prettier release that introduced support, but babel-ts looks like a built-in parser config in Prettier but relies on an external dependency of a babel plugin and I'm guessing the dependency is https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript

Comment: I would guess that the full output of error itself is somehow explicit about the WAY that the parser resolution failed but unfortunately you didn't share that output. A fragment of the error was included in the title (I missed this when reading your question, but it should have been in the question body). It's really good practice to actually provide the full output of the error so people can 'see it failing'

Comment: @tehhowch Do you have any references for this? Even looking at some prettier config files in various projects on github dont seem to follow this idea. For example https://github.com/jcoene/slack-notify-action/blob/854a9d743691a25af2707256f40acc9a4677a81a/package.json, and https://github.com/jaywcjlove/nginx-editor/blob/main/.prettierrc

Comment: FOUND A WORKAROUND**

Answer (score 4):

Found it. Require from same npm package & add it as a plugin

```
const prettier = require("prettier");
const tsParser = require("prettier/parser-typescript");

prettier.format(code, {
    parser, // https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#parser
    plugins: [tsParser],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this is frustrating. So to reiterate, the installtion was locally and not globally, but, when ran from the project directory it would return an error ONLY when using the babel-ts parser. If i selected another parser it worked fine. This could be due to some weird path logic within the library? Not sure.

HOWEVER, if I run this command prefixed by yarn ie:

```
yarn prettier --check '*.ts'
```

IT WORKS. Still find it quite odd that it only doesnt work with the babel-ts parser.

**UPDATE**:
Even though it wasn't present in my npm/yarn globals, it was still present on my linux system. Im guessing at some point I used a AUR package which hasn't been updated to prettier > 2.0. Don't forget to watch out for these!

Comment: You have another version of Prettier installed globally. It's old enough to not have `babel-ts`. When you run `prettier` without `yarn`, this version is found in your `PATH`. Locally installed packages aren't added to `PATH`.

Comment: That what i thought, but checking npm -g list and yarn global list comes up with nada. Its probably somewhere on my system though that is the only way that would make any sense.  I do use nvm, maybe its in a folder there in an older version of node

Comment: Found the culprit. Must of been a hold over from something way back when to not be tracked by node/yarn.